# Cannot checkout code from mirror repository created using svnsync

Tags: svn, mirroring, svnsync

I'm trying to create a mirror repository of an online svn repository, so i can have the source code with the ability to synchronize the changes on the online repo. and start to checkout the code from the mirror repo. to make changes on it.

After doing the steps using `svnsync` and after i did actually my first `svnsync sync` command, no source code have been copied to the mirror repo.

Am i misunderstanding the use of `svnsync` or i'm misunderstanding all the svn mirroring mechanism? How can i checkout the code from the mirror repo. and start to working on it?

**Note**
I did the following to create a mirror svn repo.

```
$ svnadmin create dest
$ cat <<'EOF' > dest/hooks/pre-revprop-change
#!/bin/sh
USER="$3"

if [ "$USER" = "svnsync" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Only the svnsync user can change revprops" >&2
exit 1
EOF

$ chmod +x dest/hooks/pre-revprop-change
$ svnsync init --username svnsync file://`pwd`/dest http://thesource/source/repos
$ svnsync sync file://`pwd`/dest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the missing step in the steps to create a mirror using `svnsync`. As described in the following [blog post and the second comment in the post](http://www.cardinalpath.com/how-to-use-svnsync-to-create-a-mirror-backup-of-your-subversion-repository/) the problem solved by dumping the public repository using the following command:

`$ svnrdump dump http://sourceRepo/svn/repo > /tmp/sourceDump`

we can optionally use `-rX` or `-rX:Y` to dump a specific revision or a revision range. After that we start to create the mirror repository using the following command:

```
$ svnadmin create destRepo
$ cat <<'EOF' > /pathToCreatedRepo/destRepo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
#!/bin/sh
USER="$3"

if [ "$USER" = "svnsync" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Only the svnsync user can change revprops" >&2
exit 1
EOF

$ chmod +x /pathToCreatedRepo/destRepo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
```

after that we need to import the dump file into the new `destRepo` using the following command

```
$ svnadmin load /pathToCreatedRepo/destRepo < /tmp/sourceDump
```

we now will do the synchronization initialization using the following command:

```
$ svnsync initialize --allow-non-empty file:///pathToCreatedRepo/destRepo http://sourceRepo/svn/repo
```

**Note** we must here add the argument `--allow-non-empty` to make SVN able to sync over the existing dump loaded previously. We can now do an ordinary `sync` call  on the new `destRepo`

```
$ svnsync sync file:///pathToCreatedRepo/destRepo
```

I'm now able to checkout code from the mirror repository :)

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,

I suggest not to treat svn repositories like git where you can push/pull commits back and forth.

If dealing with a local offline mirror is a must then git-svn is a solution here but learn it carefully first.

Comment: I'm now trying to clone the repo. using `git-svn` but the problem is in my company's internal infrastructure and they need this on SVN not GIT
Thank you Maher for your help

Comment: Do you need to maintain the public repository's history in your local mirror? Or could you do a full reimport to everything as a sort og a snapshot?

Comment: I need to keep up with the public repository's commits, but i don't care about old history

Comment: A decent cron job should do the job of exporting the public repository and importing it as a snapshot internally.

Comment: JAK Maher for your interest :)